# SQL: Union three tables with each query being dependent on the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchy

I've got a hierarchical relationship between three tables (lets say products have parts and parts have locations).  I want to get all of the products that are bicycles and all of these bicycles' parts that are gear shifters and all of these gear shifters' locations that are European.  I don't want a bike if it doesn't have gear shifters that are European and I don't want gear shifters that are European but are for cars.

I understand that I could accomplish this with two INNER JOINS, but it is my preference not to use INNER JOINS as I expect to get back 26 million rows containing a fair amount of data in each table.  I also don't really want to break it up and process it on the application side.

I'd prefer to get data in a UNIONed format, but in a way where the products I get back depend on the location and the locations I get back depend on the product, etc.  And yes, the columns I'll be getting from each table are the same (let's say I'm getting back one KEY column and one DATA column from each of the tables).  Is this possible?

Edit: Adding an example schema of how the hierarchy looks

```sql
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
    KEY_FIELD VARBINARY(1),
    DATA VARBINARY(20),
    PRODUCT_NAME AS SUBSTRING (KEY_FIELD, 1, 1) PERSISTED, 
    PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_NAME)
)

CREATE TABLE PART (
    KEY_FIELD VARBINARY(2),
    DATA VARBINARY(30),
    PRODUCT_NAME AS SUBSTRING (KEY_FIELD, 1, 1) PERSISTED,
    PART_NAME AS SUBSTRING (KEY_FIELD, 2, 1) PERSISTED,
    PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_NAME, PART_NAME),
    FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_NAME) REFERENCES PRODUCT (PRODUCT_NAME)
)

CREATE TABLE LOCATION (
    KEY_FIELD VARBINARY(3),
    DATA VARBINARY(40),
    PRODUCT_NAME AS SUBSTRING (KEY_FIELD, 1, 1) PERSISTED,
    PART_NAME AS SUBSTRING (KEY_FIELD, 2, 1) PERSISTED,
    LOCATION_NAME AS SUBSTRING (KEY_FIELD, 3, 1) PERSISTED,
    PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_NAME, PART_NAME, LOCATION_NAME),
    FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_NAME, PART_NAME) REFERENCES PART (PRODUCT_NAME, PART_NAME)
)
```

And some sample data

```sql
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES (0x01, 0x1234), (0x02, 0x5678)
INSERT INTO PART VALUES (0x0101, 0x9999), (0x0201, 0x8888), (0x0102, 0x8888), (0x0202, 0x8888)
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES (0x010101, 0xFFFF), (0x010102, 0xEEEE), (0x010201, 0xDDDD), (0x010202, 0xCCCC), (0x020101, 0xBBBB), (0x020102, 0xBBBB), (0x020201, 0xBBBB)
```

An example of my desired results:

```
    |  KEY     |  DATA   |
    |----------|---------|
    | 0x02     |  0x5678 |
    | 0x0201   |  0x8888 |
    | 0x0202   |  0x8888 |
    | 0x020101 |  0xBBBB |
    | 0x020102 |  0xBBBB |
    | 0x020201 |  0xBBBB |
```

What I don't want to do to get it

```sql
SELECT 
 t1.KEY, t2.KEY, t3.KEY, t1.DATA, t2.DATA, t3.DATA
FROM 
 PRODUCT t1
 INNER JOIN
 PART t2
 ON t1.PRODUCT_NAME = t2.PRODUCT_NAME
 INNER JOIN
 PART t3
 ON t2.PRODUCT_NAME = t3.PRODUCT_NAME
 AND t2.PART_NAME = t3.PART_NAME
WHERE
 t1.DATA = 0x5678
 AND
 t2.DATA = 0x8888
 AND
 t3.DATA = 0xBBBB
ORDER BY PRODUCT_NAME, PART_NAME, LOCATION_NAME
```

And then have to parse the results in the application.

Please note that the whole point of me doing this is for performance reasons, so the query must be more or less as performant as possible.

Comment: I recommend not hamstringing yourself by assuming that a particular technique won't perform well in advance. Write you queries in the most logical way and only if there is then a performance issue worry about trying to optimise it. SQL Server is very good at optimising if the basic indexes etc are provided.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dale.  I was coming to this forum because I need a good solution quickly.  The query generation and result handling happens dynamically in the application, as there are several hierarchies with several possible options for how you would filter them.  I likely will not have time to attempt the join approach, test it for performance, and then implement something different if it is too slow (not to mention the network I'm dealing with is not great).  A unioned approach also fits much neater with our current result processing.

Comment: "I was coming to this forum because I need a good solution quickly." that might be a misunderstanding about how this site works. The site is intended to assist with specific technical issues you run into while solving your problem. If you don't have time to write and test your approach yourself, you can't really expect us to - everyone is busy here. And without a [MRE] there is little we can do.

Comment: It is rare in the product development world that you get to just spend a bunch of time implementing something without first considering the pros and cons of different strategies and then just reimplement it if your first attempt didn't fit your needs.

Comment: And the thing with SQL is, you can't make any performance assumptions (aside from real basic stuff) without measuring the performance, so you have to start writing a query to get a sense of whether it will perform.

Comment: It's not that I haven't tested this approach.  I just haven't tested it on production data in the production environment.  And I won't have time to test it on that.  That's just the reality of the business world sometimes.  But the whole point of this task is to improve performance, so I'm weary of multiple joins that return duplicate data for 26 million rows (which could easily be in the gigabytes of extra, unnecessary data).  I appreciate the suggestion to add an example though.  And no, I did not know about accepting answers on here.

Answer (score 0):

If there are records in the `PRODUCT` and `PART` tables that don't exist in the `LOCATION` table, you can take this approach:

```sql
SELECT
  PRODUCT_NAME,
  NULL AS PART_NAME,
  NULL AS LOCATION_NAME,
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME = 'BICYCLE'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  PRODUCT_NAME,
  PART_NAME AS PART_NAME,
  NULL AS LOCATION_NAME,
FROM PART
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME = 'BICYCLE'
AND PART_NAME = 'GEAR SHIFT'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  PRODUCT_NAME,
  PART_NAME AS PART_NAME,
  LOCATION_NAME AS LOCATION_NAME,
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME = 'BICYCLE'
AND PART_NAME = 'GEAR SHIFT'
```

If all records are already available in the `LOCATION` table, which from the `FK` definition looks like they are, you can just query that:

```sql
SELECT
  PRODUCT_NAME,
  PART_NAME AS PART_NAME,
  LOCATION_NAME AS LOCATION_NAME,
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME = 'BICYCLE'
AND PART_NAME = 'GEAR SHIFT'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  The issue is that I might be possibly filtering the PRODUCT on fields from the LOCATION that are not in the PRODUCT table.  So I may need all PRODUCTS that have a LOCATION with LOCATION_CODE = 1234 but that location code is not found in the PRODUCTS table.  I also may need all LOCATIONS where the PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION is METAL or something like that.  I'll edit my example to clarify that a bit more.